# Multiple Subdomains in one Google Analytics Account

Tags: google-analytics

I know this question has been asked before, but I do not understand the solution and google did an update to the analytics so the settings are not the same.

I've got a domain, lets say test.de
I've got ca. 50 subdomains, like item1.test.de, item2.test.de etc.
They all show the same folder in my FTP.

I want to track all of my subdomains, which are dynamically created, in one Analytics Account.

How do I do that? I had to set a domain name, but I have 50 different subdomains. So how?

Comment: the number 50 that you say is fixed or will it increase to 100 or so at some point of time ?

Answer (score 1):

The data will be tracked without further adaptations to the code if you set the cookie domain parameter correctly (see the answer from Herr Kreuz).

The domain name you enter in the admin section does not matter for tracking (data will be collected regardless of domain). It is used in the inpage analyses report. Also it's used when you click the tiny arrow beside the page paths in the behavior report (it will be prepended to the page path when GA tries to open that page in a popup).

The real problem is that similar page paths from your subdomains will be conflated in the reports (i.e. if you have an index.php on three different domains the behavior report will show the conflated number for all three domains). As a temporary measure you could select "hostname" as a secondary dimension, for a lasting solution you might consider a [filter that adds the (sub-) domainname to each page path](http://www.annielytics.com/blog/analytics/how-to-add-a-hostname-filter-in-ga/).

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y','auto');
```

The **auto** parameter is important in your case.